# powershell: find results in an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, wmi, powershell-2.0

I've have a list of 10 windows services in an array from computer "A" and i want retrieve the same list in computer "B".

I have retrieved the list on computer "B" using WMI (it has to be WMI because i want the start-up mode).

This is the code i used:

```
$IssueService = "Browser", "Dhcp", "Dnscache", "dwmrcs", "iphlpsvc", "LanmanServer", "LanmanWorkstation", "MMCSS", "MpsSvc", "Netlogon", "Netman", "netprofm", "NlaSvc", "nsi", "p2pimsvc","PNRPsvc","PolicyAgent", "SessionEnv", "stisvc", "W32Time", "WinHttpAutoProxySvc", "WinRM"
$Services = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service
$Services | Where-Object {$IssueService.name -contains $_.name}
```

Any help is appreciated, I'm new(ish) to PowerShell so a explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `$IssueService.name` to `$IssueService`. There is no `name` property in your string array. The item to the left of the `-contains` operator needs to be a collection rather than a single item.

Comment: Thanks I have the script working.  i wasn't sure what you meant by "The item to the left of the -contains operator needs to be a collection rather than a single item.". can you expand please?